# R scope rules for nested functions

Tags: r, scope

I am trying to use R's lexical scoping with 2 levels of functions, but the behavior in R 3.0.2 does not seem right.

```
foo = function() print(ii)
eye_foo = function( ) { 
    ii = 1  # (A)
    foo()
}
eye_foo()   # (B)
ii=2        # (C)
eye_foo()   # (D)
```

I would expect that (B) would print "1", binding to the variable defined at (A).  Instead (B) gives an error message "Error in print(ii) : object 'ii' not found".  However, after defining ii at (C) in the global scope, (D) prints "2" ignoring (A) in the process.

Why is (A) being ignored?

Comment: I actually do something like this too, though it's probably bad practice. My solution is to use expressions: `foo <- expression(print(ii)); eye_foo2 <- function() {ii <- 1; eval(foo)}`. If you use `eval(foo)` anywhere except eye_foo2, it will use the value it finds in the global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` was defined in the global environment. At the time of the first call to `eye_foo` there was no value for `ii` to be found in the environment where foo was created. Then you made a value to be found and got the expected results. Simple as that.

```
> environment(foo)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

 ?'function'
 ?globalenv
```

Generally people avoid this conundrum by passing arguments to functions.

Comment: thanks, I got mixed up between lexical and dynamic scoping.  the code should have been

    eye_foo = function( ) {
        foo = function() print(ii)
        ii = 1  # (A)
        foo()
    }
    eye_foo()   # (B)
    ii=2        # (C)
    eye_foo()   # (D)

which yields the behavior I was expecting.

Comment: I say again: Generally people avoid this conundrum by passing arguments to functions.